# Why does hot reload not work when running a Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App on .Net 8?

Tags: visual-studio, hot-reload

I created a new project and tried to run it, it works fine but when i add even just a `<h2>` tag and clicking hot reload does not seem to work. It may say that "Code changes were applied successfully" but it really doesn't change the value inside the `<h2>` tag

What I did is just to stop debugging then run it again. It is really a hassle to do it. I updated my VS Professional 2022 to v.17.8.3 but still doesn't work.